# Best way to swap IBM PC case badge?

Tags: ibm-pc, ibm, case

[image: IBM PC case badge]
[image: IBM PC XT case badge]

A while back, I purchased an original IBM PC (5150). The seller had an improper top case or badge on it, as the badge actually said it was an XT (5160) instead. After confirming that it is indeed a 5150 (for example, only 5 ISA slots), I waited until I could find either a replacement case or badge for it. As you'd assume, these don't come around too often, but recently I was able to acquire a replacement badge.

I'd like to get opinions on the best way to:

1. Remove the IBM PC XT badge
2. Attach the proper IBM PC badge

Any thoughts on tools to use or what sort of adhesive I should apply to it? Are these badges really tough on there? I'd hate to damage the XT badge as well.

Comment: Try putting the case panel in your freezer. The low temperature may make the adhesive brittle enough to crack, if you can flex the case from the inside before it warms up again.

Comment: Gentle heat is the other method commonly used to soften adhesive enough to prise the badge off - i.e. a hairdryer on low heat. But I'm talking in general and not sure if there's a risk with the materials you're dealing with.

Comment: Prizing off the old badge risks damaging it by bending it (it looks like brushed aluminium to me, not plastic). You can clean up the old adhesive more safely from both the badge and the case after they are separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alephzero's suggestion of cold is a good one. I've used dry ice to release adhesive on a 3d printer's build plate (PEI sheet) which is held by a 3M adhesive. Dry ice is not particularly inexpensive and you'd need only a small piece for about two or three minutes.

Various products designed to release/dissolve glue, often called Goo-gone or similar would work. You'd want to build a dam around the badge, with the case front positioned horizontally, to allow the stuff to soak in thoroughly.

Some have used products such as WD-40 to accomplish similar results.

Comment: The cans of freeze spray can work well too.